# Propagate property changes through multiple classes

Tags: c#, properties

I'm trying to figure out how to properly pass properties through multiple classes. I know I can just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in each class and listen for changes on the property, but this seems to be quite a lot of unnecessary code.

The situation:
I have a class (let's call it `Class1`) with two dependency properties: `FilterStatement` (String) and `Filter` (Filter class). Setting the statement affects the filter and vice versa. 
The conversion logic between statement and filter, however, isn't located in `Class1`, but in `Class3` - which `Class1` doesn't know directly. In between there is `Class2` which just has to pass through the changes. (You can imagine class 1 to 3 beeing Viewmodel, Model and Repository, though in the real situation this doesn't completly match).

```
public class Class1
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Filter",
        typeof(Filter),
        typeof(Class1),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterStatementProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "FilterStatement",
        typeof(String),
        typeof(Class1),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public Filter Filter
    {
        get { return (Filter)GetValue(FilterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FilterProperty, value); }
    }

    public string FilterStatement
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FilterStatementProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FilterStatementProperty, value); }
    }

    public Class2 MyClass2Instance { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public Class3 MyClass3Instance { get; set; }

    public void ChangeClass3Instance(object someParam) {
        ...  // this can change the instance of MyClass3Instance and is called frome somewhere else
        // when changed, the new Class3 instance has to get the property values of Class1
    }
}

public class Class3
{
    private Filter _filter; // here is where the filter set in Class 1 or determined by the statement set in class 1 has to be put

    public string MyFilterToStatementConversionMemberFunction(Filter filter)
    {
        ...
    }

    public Filter MyStatementToFilterConversionMemberFunction(string statement)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My naive solution would be to duplicate the properties across all three classes, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `Class2` and `Class3` and listen to the changes, propagating everything down to `Class3` and in Result back up to `Class1`. Isn't there a better solution to this?

Comment: Could you not use a messenger like the one in MVVM light. Basically its designed so that you can notify property changes across VMs which don't need to know about each other.

Comment: I'm currently not using one, and I'd like to avoid to use one just for this.... but yeah you are right, that could be a solution

Comment: Yeah thats why I thought I would post a comment instead of an answer. It looks like you could be heading down the road of not doing the right thing because you think there's a better way of doing it. But you know your project better than me so I am sure there is a reason, just be careful ;)

Comment: I didn't get, why `Class1` doesn't know about `Class3`, if you can just make call of `this.MyClass2Instance.MyClass3Instance.MyStatementToFilterConversionMemberFunction("")` right from the `Class1`?

Comment: you are right... let me think about that for a moment, i'm not sure if i can just jump over class2 or if there is a case where I need to pass it through

Comment: @EugeneBerdnikov i evaluated the situation, and i have a reason why i can't just use a direct connecion: the instance of class3, that class2 knows, could be replaced. I don't see a good way for class1 to notice this and unregister the events on the old class und register the new ones

Comment: Currently there are no any events in the code provided by you. So, direct using still looks like a good solution. Could you please update the code example to make the issue with events more clear?

Comment: I edited the code

Comment: Sorry, but it still isn't clear. While the `MyClass3Instance` property provides a setter, you can unsubscribe/subscribe on your events there. So, what stops you to do a direct call of `Class3` methods in the `PropertyChangedCallback` handler of your DPs?

Comment: if i register my events between class1 and class3, and some other class changes the instance in class2 with the function i added, how should class1 notice and reroute the events

Comment: The solution I'm talking about doesn't assume introducing any new events. Please add any events your implementation already has to the code example.

Comment: it has none, I just assumed I'd need them - how else should class1 notice changes in class3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, while `Class1` is not a control (given it is a ViewModel) I don't see a reason to make its properties as `DependencyProperty`, because implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` should be enough.
However, implementation with `DependencyProperty` should work as well:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Filter),
            typeof(Filter),
            typeof(Class1),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterStatementProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(FilterStatement),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(Class1),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnPropertyChanged));

    public Filter Filter
    {
        get { return (Filter)GetValue(FilterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FilterProperty, value); }
    }

    public string FilterStatement
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FilterStatementProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FilterStatementProperty, value); }
    }

    public Class2 MyClass2Instance { get; set; }

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var c = (Class1)d;
        if (c.MyClass2Instance?.MyClass3Instance != null)
        {
            if (e.Property == FilterProperty)
            {
                c.FilterStatement = c.MyClass2Instance.MyClass3Instance.MyFilterToStatementConversionMemberFunction((Filter)e.NewValue);
            }
            else if (e.Property == FilterStatementProperty)
            {
                c.Filter = c.MyClass2Instance.MyClass3Instance.MyStatementToFilterConversionMemberFunction((string)e.NewValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, `Filter.Equals` should be implemented properly and conversion methods of the `Class3` should return the equal values for equal arguments.

Comment: ok, now I understand what you meant by "directly" - I have to give a thought about responsibilities, but this looks good. I was to focused in events to come up with that solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you complicate this too much. Observable pattern is better fit to user interface implementation. Why don't you code in `Class3` logic which set all propertis in `Class1` ? I thnik that overload setter `FilterStatment`and `Filter` in `Class1`, which is ViewModel is good solution as well. As simpler solution as better.

Comment: While `Class1` knows `Class2` and `Class2` knows `Class3`, this isn't true the other way round - I can't set the properties of `Class1` from `Class3` and also I don't want to do this, because the responsibilities are wrong.

Comment: I'll build an example of the class structure